# Build an dynamic if statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, if-statement, dynamic

How can i build an dynamic if statement that also includes <, >, ==, <=, >=
I want to build an dynamic if statement that is not looking like this:

```
if (seconds < choosedSeconds)
{

}
else if (seconds > choosedSeconds)
{

}
else if(seconds >= choosedSeconds)
{

}
else if(seconds == choosedSeconds)
{

}
```

This is what i want it to look like

```
if(seconds myOperator choosedSeconds) // or minutes, hours and so on
{

}
```

I just want to have that in one statement.
Do i have to build a struct for that?

An example would be nice.

Comment: look up `QBE` it stands for `Query By Example` very simple process

Comment: personally I would do a `Switch Case Statement` then you can do a case on multiple integer values at once

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense. Can you elaborate a bit more on what it is you want to do?

Comment: You know there are only three kinds of comparison results of two numbers: `less`, `equal` and `greater`. Why do you need 5 `if`s?

Comment: i want to build an statement where i can put in dynamic input like the seconds that also could be minutes, hours, days or so on and an operator like <, > .. and again seconds, hours, days and so on. The statement should be build by the user.

Comment: In your example, if seconds equals choosedSeconds, it would never execute the `seconds == choosedSeconds` block because the `>=` would get it

Comment: @user3438236 Clarify what you mean by a "dynamic if statement". There isn't anything like that in C#

Comment: He essentially wants the comparison operator to be user defined.

Comment: It's not just the operator. I want everything in the if statement to be user definied.

Comment: @user3438236 Yes we know that. You have several answers to your problem below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with delegates and lambda expressions

```
void MyMethod (Func<int, int, bool> comparison)
{
    int seconds = ...;
    int chosenSeconds = ...;

    if (comparison(seconds, chosenSeconds)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can call it like this

```
MyMethod((a, b) => a <= b);
```

or

```
MyMethod((a, b) => a == b);
```

Any comparison will work as long as the expression is a Boolean expression:

```
MyMethod((a, b) => a % b == 0);
MyMethod((a, b) => array[a] == 100 * b + 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
interface IMyConditionEvaluator 
{
    bool EvaluateCondition(int x, int y); 
}

…

IMyConditionEvaluator e = new SomeSpecificConditionEvaluator();

…

if (e.EvaluateCondition(seconds, choosedSeconds))
{
    …
}
```

Now go ahead and create as many classes implementing `IMyConditionEvaluator` as you wish.

Comment: I have 2 questions.                                                   1. Why an interface and why IMyConditionEvaluator e = new SomeSpecificConditionEvaluator(); shouldn't it be new IMyConditionEvaluator?                                              2. How could i add for example an comparison for >= could you give me an Example?

Comment: You are apparently missing the basics. I suggest you get accustomed with the language first.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with [predicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e:

```cs
public bool IsExactlyOneSecond(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    return timeSpan.TotalSeconds == 1.0;
}

public bool IsMoreThanOneSecond(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    return timeSpan.TotalSeconds > 1.0;
}
```

Then you probably have some method taking the predicate as input:

```
private void Process(TimeSpan timeSpan, Predicate<TimeSpan> test)
{
    if (test(timeSpan))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
Process(timeSpan, IsExactlyOneSecond);
```

Or

```
Process(timeSpan, IsMoreThanOneSecond);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this? This generic method compares two values using the specified comparison type.

```
public enum ComparisonType
{
    Equal,
    Less,
    Greater,
    LessOrEqual,
    GreaterOrEqual
}

public static bool Compare<T>(T a, ComparisonType compType, T b)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    switch (compType)
    {
        case ComparisonType.Equal:
            return a.CompareTo(b) == 0;
        case ComparisonType.Less:
            return a.CompareTo(b) < 0;
        case ComparisonType.Greater:
            return a.CompareTo(b) > 0;
        case ComparisonType.LessOrEqual:
            return a.CompareTo(b) <= 0;
        case ComparisonType.GreaterOrEqual:
            return a.CompareTo(b) >= 0;
    }
    throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

Usage example:

```
if (Compare(seconds, ComparisonType.LessOrEqual, choosenSeconds))
{
    // seconds <= choosenSeconds here
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at 
[Expression Trees](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=c#%20expressions&oq=c#%20expressions&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.3564j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: This is, at best, a comment; not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 Sure it does, it's just not in English.

Comment: @Sevy no it doesn't. It brings me to https://www.google.co.il/search?q=c#. Linking to a google search is not an appropriate answer either.

Comment: oops - ,my mistake - wrong url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx